# Bivariate probit : is there a heteroscedastic version of the model?

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, probit, bivariate

I know there exists a version of the simple probit model which is robust to heteroscedasticity (the heteroscedastic probit model). Is there an equivalent for the bivariate probit model? Is there a way to implement it in R if it exists?